# Entering text into JavaFX TextField freezes application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

in our JavaFX application different customers get more or less sporadically the following error while entering text in TextField's. As a result, the rendering framework seems to run into an endless loop in which the error below is repeatedly printed into the System console. From there, the application freezes completely, must be killed and restarted which is a complete showstopper for those customers.

Threading issues (Fx and worker threads) are not involved in this place.

The bug occurs in Windows 7 and 10, Java 1.8.0_171, but as I remember it occured also with previous Java versions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
            at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
            at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
            at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
            at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
            at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
            at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3595)
            at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3625)
            at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3486)
            at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
            at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
            at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
            at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
            at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For me it's clearly an programming error in Parent.java:1591 since remainingDirtyNodes seems to be not in sync with dirtyNodes list but no bounds check is done for dirtyNodes, causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks, Peter

PS: Apart from this, JavaFX seems to run impressively stable and it is fun to work with.

Comment: Were you able to isolate the minimal source code where this issue can be reproduced (at least sporadically, as mentioned)?

Comment: Isolating is actually non-trivial in our case. The bug in our application occurs almost only on customer PC's, and this not reliably (in contrast to the minimal example desribed in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163078). Interestingly, it occurs only when a user wants to edit TextField's. For now, I'll go on with testing my own workaround suggestions, see comment in Michaels answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, related to "removing a Node from the scene graph"

It's still without a fix, scheduled for release in Open JFX 11. I'm not sure when you can expect a release, as JavaFX is being split out from the JDK, and this issue has been open for two years already.

The ticket includes a minimal example, so probably the best you can hope for is to find a correlation in how you manipulate the scene graph and work around the issue.

See: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163078

Comment: MIchael, thank you very much for this comment. I agree that the bug might be related to removal of nodes from the scene graph, using Node.getChildren().setAll() or similar. I looked also at the minimal example in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163078 and could reproduce the bug. Interestingly, setting the prefSize of the parent node holding the Text node to a fixed value OR setting the visibility of the Text node to false before removing it the bug does not occur. I’m going to check if this might be a workaround for our case. Waiting for Open JFX 11 is not a suitable option ;-)

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Sorry it wasn't more conclusive. Perhaps if you find any more info you could leave an answer here of your own to help others struggling with the same issue.